# How to make your desktop Java app looks like Open Office or Eclipse etc.?

Tags: java, deployment

How to make your desktop Java app looks like Open Office or Eclipse  etc ?
Installation process looks like any Windpws app. installation. There is no Java logo on the to on a app window. You run it by .exe file. How it is done? Is this jar->exe conversion?
Is there any free tool to do that?

Comment: This question is very unclear. Am I correct in assuming that what you want is to be able to open and run your application by double-clicking an icon, or are you after something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the native look, you can obviously go the SWT way, like Eclipse does, however it's a painful one. You could/should prefer the Swing look'n'feel, by using, as an example, the [Substance Look'n'Feel](https://substance.dev.java.net/).

For the installation part, you can use

- [InstallAnywhere](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installanywhere.htm)
- [IzPack](http://izpack.org/)

For the exe wrapper, you can use

- [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)
- [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

or others ...

However, I think that, by doing so, you're doing it wrong.
indeed, instead of the classical download/install step, which is cumbersome, you can go the Java Web Start way : user only has to click one webpage link to install application to its machine (with an update mechanism directly integrated in), an install that go as far as potentially including desktop and start menu shortcuts, and an element in the Windows install panel to remove installed software.

Answer (score 2):

I tried [Jar2Exe](http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/), and [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/), they both produce exe files from jar archives.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a little unclear, but I think that what you're after is making your java app behave like a native app (stuff like running it when an icon is double-clicked, etc...). There is an excellent tutorial on this [here](http://today.java.net/article/2003/12/04/make-your-swing-app-go-native-part-2).

Answer (score 1):

Note that, for the graphic part, Eclipse uses a library called [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/), which is a set of widgets that feel and behave in a different way that Java Swing or AWT.

Anyway, if you go the normal Java (Swing) way, the Java logo on the top of an app window is [setIconImage()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29) method in JFrame components.

Riduidel already told you about .exe wrappers and installers you can use. For the installer, I also suggest you to consider Java Web Start instead of a normal Windows installer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it uses LookAndFeel, I let you read: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

```
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

EDIT: I didn't read the entire question ^^' Maybe it will be useful to someone...